# Spyder IDE: Previous and Next Cursor Position shortcuts are not working properly at all

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder, shortcut

I will often use Ctrl+G to go to a definition of some variable and then use the "previous cursor position" shortcut to go back to where I was after viewing. This is easy to achieve in Eclipse. But in Spyder, the previous cursor position shortcut (I left as the default Ctrl+alt+Left) takes me to seemingly completely random places. It even takes me to files I haven't touched in months! I checked that the shortcut is not being overridden by another command so I'm not sure what the issue is. I am using Spyder 4.0.1.

Comment: Maybe could be worthy for you to do an update. The latest Spyder release is 5.3.1. If you use anaconda/conda you will need to create a new env using the conda-forge channel (the default channel doesn't have the latest Spyder version). Also, if you are using Windows or MacOS, you could check the standalone installers available at the Spyder release page: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/latest

Comment: @DanielAlthviz Thanks but this shortcut has been standard on Spyder since the beginning from what I know. Do you have any ideas to try and work this out for what might be happening here? Thanks

Comment: Checking the Spyder issue tracker on GitHub seems like some issues regarding that functionality where fixed with Spyder 4.1.3: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12521 Also, in the latest version (5.3.1) that functionality was binded with the extra buttons you can find on some mouses: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15948 maybe you could check the changelogs to see if there is an specific version that includes fixes to the cursor position functionality: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/tree/5.x/changelogs